# ComboBox, is there an event for item hover?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, combobox, adobe

I'm using the `<s:ComboBox>` flex component which I suspect is very similar to the mx one `<mx:ComboBox>`

What I'm trying to do is listen to the event of the mouse moving between the items of the list. There's a `change` event, but it kicks in only when the item is clicked/selected from the list.

What event would I need to listen for when items are just hovered over. I tried finding `over` and `hover` but couldn't find something to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

No on hover event, but there is a mouseOver event that should be able to do what you want.

Comment: This is for the comboBox itself, not each of its items. Does that mean I'd have to create an event listener for each item of the comboBox, that sounds a little too painful and well too painful.

Comment: The dropdown portion of the comboBox is actualy a list. If you extend the comboBox you should be able to add the mouse over to that list to do what you want.

Comment: Not sure if that's really needed. I've tried doing something like `myCombo.dropDown.addEventListener(ListEvent.ITEM_ROLL_OVER, someHandleEvent);` but had no luck. I doubt I need to extend the comboBox though because something like this seems to work in Flash.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
CMM_name.dropdown.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, func_name);

function func_name(e:Event){
//DO SOmthing
}
```